# Post values from an HTML form and access them in a Flask view

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an HTML form that gets posted to a Flask route.  However, `request.form` is empty.  If I try to access one of the values by id, I get a 400 error.  How do I post values from an HTML form and access them in Flask?

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input id="my_input" type="text" value="{{ email }}">
  <input id="my_submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
@app.route('/page', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.form)  # prints ImmutableMultiDict([])
        print(request.form['my_input'])  # raises 400 error
    return render_template('page.html')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `input` doesn't have a [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-name) attribute. That is what the client will pass along to the server. Flask will raise a 400 error if you access a form key that wasn't submitted.

```html
<input name="my_input" id="my_input" type="text" value="{{ email }}">
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to Specify the form Action method in the Html page, and then mention the HTML Text box name inside the  Tag.

```
<form method="POST" action="/PythonFunctionName">
  <input id="my_input" type="text" name="HTMLControlName" value="{{ email }}">
  <input id="my_submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And inside the .py module access the element using the name specified in the HTML  tag.

```
@app.route('/PythonFunctionName', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def getPage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        strTextBoxVal= request.form['HTMLControlName'])
        Print(strTextBoxVal) 
    return render_template('page.html')
```