# I am trying to do login in flask but request.form is giving any data

Tags: flask

I am trying to create simple login in flask but i am not getting data in blackened

my html look like

```
{% extends "layouts/home.html" %}
{% block body %}
{% block css %}
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/v2/login.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="account-wall">
                <img class="profile-img" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b0-k99FZlyE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/eu7opA4byxI/photo.jpg?sz=120"
                    alt="">
                <form role="form" class="form-signin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url_for('login_success')}}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                    Sign in</button>
                <label class="checkbox pull-left">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">
                    Remember me
                </label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my flask code look like

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login-success', methods=['POST'])
def login_success():
    if request.form:
        print request.form
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

but request.form is none i am not able to understand what could be possibly wrong

Comment: I tried request.stream as well  but not getting any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not like you are not getting output of request.form .If you try to print request.form then must be getting immutable dictionary in back-end but it must be empty because whenever you try to post a form then http  send form data in form object . But in your case you are not giving key of object so yo are getting empty dictionary . If you give key then you will get output.

In your html your should write like

```
<input type="text" name ="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
```

And in back-end try something like this

```
print request.form['email]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the property 'name' to all your fields, for example:

```
 <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
```

A better way to go if you're going to deal with forms is the Flask-WTF package.

Also note you're question has been asked already, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674322/get-post-values-in-flask-using-form). For these matters, there's usually an answer on stackoverflow, just look for it. It will save you time and avoid duplicates on this site.