# How to render an image to display.html after taking form input from the user in index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, flask, request

I am using a flask app which is running on my machine (local server). I want to perform this task:

The user chooses an image and that image is rendered to a template.

I do not want to upload the image file to any folder. Many questions were answered based on how the user chooses an image and uploads it to a different folder.

Instead, all I want to do is get the image from form input and display it in the browser.

I have referred a number of resources: 
1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2fMCxLz6wM
2. [How to pass uploaded image to template.html in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262518/how-to-pass-uploaded-image-to-template-html-in-flask)
3. [Post values from an HTML form and access them in a Flask view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674322/post-values-from-an-html-form-and-access-them-in-a-flask-view)

However, all of them mostly mention about uploading images to a folder before displaying

This is my main.py

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/display", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def display():
    filename = request.form.get("file")
    return render_template("display.html", image_name=filename)
```

index.html

```
<form id="display-img" action="http://localhost:5000/display" enctype=multipart/form-data method="POST">

<p>Image Select
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"></p> 

        <button>SUBMIT</button> 

</form>
```

display.html

```
<body>
    {% extends "template.html" %}
    {% block content %}

    <h1> Displayed here </h1>

    <img id="blah" src=" {{ url_for('display', file=image_name)}}">

    {% endblock %}
    <script>

        function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        }

        $("#imgInp").change(function() {
        readURL(this);
        });
    </script>
```

The actual output is:

The user should be able to choose an image from a folder (index.html). When I hit submit, the template display.html is getting rendered but the image is a **broken link image symbol**

What I expect is:

The user should be able to choose an image from a folder (index.html). When I hit submit, it is rendered to display page (display.html).

I've tried different ways to pass the image name variable to the display path, but I am still not getting the image rendered correctly.
[This is how the rendered page looks so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSEGD.jpg)

edit: added the code for JS in display.html

Comment: You need to use javascript for that here answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Hi @rampandey yes I used it, still it is a broken image. I'll edit the question with rest of the code. I have used JS in display.html

Comment: I realized that the image variable is not being passed from form input (in index.html) to request.form.get("file") (in main.py). So I changed request.form.get("file") ->  request.files.getlist("file"). However, the variable getting passed to file is [<FileStorage: 'dog.png' ('image/png')>]. I need to make sure only dog.png gets passed. How should I do that?